# rest service get file parameters in yii

Tags: web-services, rest, yii

Hi i try to get file from postman in google chroome.
And I try to get file parameters, size, type.

This is logic of the solution

```
If($_POST)
    {
        $document='document_from_postman.docx'
        $size = file size of $document
        $tip = file type of $document


    }
$size sent to database.
$tip sent to database.
```

But I don't know how to implement this in yii controller, how to get key value from postman, i never work with web service before.How to put document name from postman in variable example:
$document='document_from_postman.docx'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use

`$file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');`

in your controller. Than you can get size and type of file

```
  echo $file->size;
  echo $file->type;
```

To write to database you already know i think what to do. Example:

```
 $file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file')
 $model->size =  $file->size;
 $model->type = $file->type;
 $model->save()
```